# Hanging on “Please wait for the User Profile Service” while shutting down, NOT logging in

Tags: domain-controller, user-profile, shutdown

When we shut down our DC and the servers on the domain, it hangs on the “Please wait for the User Profile Service” screen for a very long time. Not logging IN, but shutting down. Trying to google the solution only takes me to the error that occurs during logging in, so please forgive me if this problem has a simple solution.

It will shut down eventually, however, it takes a very long time.

EDIT Also, we cannot login to a new domain server with the Domain Administrator account, the user profile will not work but it works on our current servers and DC so it is not corrupt.

Any solution would be very appreciated!

Comment: Regarding your edit, note that the domain administrator account (like all accounts) should have a different profile on each computer it logs into.  Profiles are not normally shared between computers, not even between domain controllers.  (You *can* configure roaming profiles, but it isn't recommended.)

Comment: Regarding the main question, are there any errors appearing in the event logs that might give a clue as to the cause of the problem?  Does it only affect servers and not other machines in the same domain?